# PrimeFaces p:barChart settings

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

I'm trying to use the PrimeFaces chart bar component. I configured some settings, but I am having problems with some settings. I want to completely remove the part I put in the yellow box. I also want to shorten the area indicated by the green arrow. How can I do it?

[image]

The settings on the xhtml and bean side are as follows.

xhtml:

```html
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <span style="float: left;">Toplam Kazancınız</span>
        <span style="float: right;">#{toplamKazancBean.kko.kazancToplam} TRY</span>
    </f:facet>
    <p:barChart model="#{toplamKazancBean.stackedBarModel}" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;" />
</p:panel>
```

bean:

```java
private void chartSettings() {
    // values:
    stackedBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
    ChartData data = new ChartData();

    HorizontalBarChartDataSet barDataSet = new HorizontalBarChartDataSet();

    for (int i = 0; i < kko.getKazanclarList().size(); i++) {
        int oran = (int) Math.floor(kko.getKazanclarList().get(i).getTutar() / kko.getKazancToplam() * 100);

        barDataSet.setLabel(kko.getKazanclarList().get(i).getMetinAlani() + " %" + oran);
        barDataSet.setBackgroundColor(rgbArray[i]);
        List<Number> dataVal = new ArrayList<Number>();
        dataVal.add(kko.getKazanclarList().get(i).getTutar());
        barDataSet.setData(dataVal);

        data.addChartDataSet(barDataSet);
    }

    stackedBarModel.setData(data);

    // Options
    CartesianScaleLabel label = new CartesianScaleLabel();
    label.setDisplay(false);
    
    AxesGridLines gridLines = new AxesGridLines();
    gridLines.setDisplay(false);//ızgaralar kapandı

    CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
    linearAxes.setStacked(true);
    linearAxes.setGridLines(gridLines);
    linearAxes.setScaleLabel(label);

    CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
    cScales.addXAxesData(linearAxes);
    cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
    cScales.setDisplay(true);
    
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    tooltip.setEnabled(false);
    
    BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
    options.setScales(cScales);
    options.setTooltip(tooltip);
    options.setOffsetGridLines(false);

    stackedBarModel.setOptions(options);
}
```

Comment: you will have to check out to do it with straight Charts.JS then it should be easy to figure out how to make PF do that but the real trick is figuring out how to do it without PrimeFaces in ChartsJS